# Using Leaflet map in php page

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I was searching for free maps as an alternative to google maps to use in my website. As I searched I found [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/index.html). Referring the [tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples.html) I tried creating a simple map in my localhost. But its loading blank. I am using leaflet for the first time. Is there anything I am missing out in my code? Can anyone help  me..? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
   <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
   <style>
       #map{ height: 100% }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var map = L.map('map',{
            center: [43.64701, -79.39425],
            zoom: 15
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a tile layer to your map and try using one of the latest  leaflet versions, such as 1.3.3. Moreover set a height like this:

```
#map{ height: 500px }
```

Try this

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([43.64701, -79.39425], 15);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
  .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
  .openPopup();
```

```css
#map {
  height: 500px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css">

<script src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js
'></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: In the fiddle its fine. But when I try in localhost its not getting.

Comment: place your js code under the div of map not in the head. See view-source:https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example.html

Comment: What is this tile layer meant for? I ddint understand the use of it..!

Comment: The tile layer defines the url source that your map will be rendered. The map is consisted of small images that are placed together and then you see the result of a map. You need to define the map source that these images will be taken from